# Assigning Keyboard shortcut other than ALT in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, keyboard, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Just read about [Assigning a Keyboard shortcut to a button in an Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824123/assigning-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-button-in-an-access-2007-form). By using `&` in front of Caption of any control.
For example if want to assign `Alt + N` to a button, in Caption Property put `&New`

But this only assigns `Alt`.

Here are my Questions

- `&` is to assign Alt, which is the symbol for `Ctlr`?
- What about  and `Shift` and Function Keys like `F3`?
  Can these be assigned?
- Is there any VBA code, or Property to add keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

For keys like `F1`, `F2`, `F3` so on, you may code it directly in the VBA code, with a case/ or if else statement by checking for each `vbKeyF1`, `vbKeyF2` etc with a KeyPress, KeyDown event trigger.

Take a look at these two references for using Autokey Macro as well. 
[Run an Access macro by using a keyboard shortcut.](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Run-an-Access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-0d267570-d3da-46eb-9bfb-a3c81af676be)

[Assigning Auto Keys for Aligning Controls.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-05.html)