# When I am trying to give data to text control in ms access 2003 application, The & symbol is not displaying. How to resolve this

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003

```
Text35.caption="Sugar & water"
```

But output is displaying as Sugar Water. the '&' symbol is missing

Comment: If it has a `.Caption`, it is a label, not a text box. A single & is used to assign a hotkey: `My &control` -> My _c_ontrol, which can be accessed by Alt+c

Comment: can you clearly explain how to achieve this  @Andre

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/826041/3820271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doubling the character i.e.

```
Text35.caption="Sugar && water"
```